# Wordpress/CSS - picture doesn't show up

Tags: css, wordpress, image

The first thing I'd like to point out is that I know almost nothing about CSS. At the moment I'm trying to create a website using Wordpress and I want to add an image that acts like a link and which changes to another image when the mouse is hovering over it.
I found following tutorial for this: https://www.organicweb.com.au/17523/wordpress/image-link-css/

I've done exactly what this tutorial says (basically it's more or less just copy & paste), but my image won't show up and I have absolutely no idea why. Even stranger is that the image **does** show up when I use a definite image size in the stylesheet (for example: "width: 300px; heigth: 250px;"). But it doesn't work when I use "background-size: cover;", "background-size: contain;", "background-size: auto;" or any other possibility.

This works:

```
.ge-link { 
    background-image: url(http://.../wp-content/uploads/2017/02/325484_1280.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    width: 300px;
    hight: 250px;
    display: block;
```

This doesn't work:

```
.ge-link { 
    background-image: url(http://.../uploads/2017/02/325484_1280.jpg); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
```

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Those image urls don't look right, did you just do that to remove the website name or are you really linking like that?

Answer (score 0):

what I guess you could do is to have both images together in your html and use :hover to show a different image once the main image is hovered:

HTML

```
 <a id="linkId" href="www.yourlink">

 <img class="image_on" src="yourFirstImage.png" alt="picture">

 <img class="image_off" src="yourSeconfImage" alt="picture 2">


 </a>
```

CSS

```
 .image_off, .link-block:hover .image_on{
    display:none
 }
 .image_on, .link-block:hover .image_off{
    display:block
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.ge-link` is not an image tag, it's just a container that has a background image. In the second case, you didn't define a height for that container (also no width, but that's not the primary cause for your problem), so that container is 0 pixels high - no heigth! It actually contains the background image, but with 0 heigth it doesn't show anything.

So just use those width and especially height settings as long as you use the image as a background image. Or use a real image element (`<img>`).

P.S.:  You can use the width/height settings *and* `background-size:  cover` - works perfectly...